# My HDD making weird noise

Tags: hard-drive, sata

My HDD Seagate desktop SM000T003 was making a weird noise like a deep noise (osculating hum it makes a crash hum and makes a spin up noise constantly this is 3 second long)

And when I power it on it shows Black screen blinking underscore. And Sometimes when I get it to work it works well until I open my game and it gives me a bsod saying Page_fault_in_nonpage_area

I think it is the sata cable or the psu is not giving the HDD enough power

Windows 7
7 year old pre assembled pc
H81M-CS Asus motherboard
Techno power supply

Please help me fix this

Comment: I tested it with Crystal disk info and no errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's unlikely the PSU is "not giving the HDD enough power" since, I assume, you were using the same PSU when it was working before the HDD made noise.  What is more likely, since you indicate, you receive a BSOD when you load a game, your HDD is starting to fail.  The solution to that problem is to replace the HDD ASAP before you start to lose data or the HDD itself believes it's starting to fail.

Comment: I think it's the sata because i plugged my HDD in another pc ant it is working fine no noise and the sata cable is wigglling left right

Comment: Is the drive securely screwed in place? There is a lot of accelerating torque involved when it starts to spin up.

Comment: Yes it is very tightly screwed

Comment: Please edit your question and include the SMART values (no idea if Crystal disk provides them, if not, use a different tool). Seek errors or spin up errors will show up in the SMART values. "Page fault in non-page area" is an indication that something else on your computer besides the harddisk is broken (possibly RAM, but could be everything, including a PSU fault).

Comment: Yes it is very tightly screwed   ........  Is it overly tight?  It need not be and overly tight may distort the case a very small amount causing noise.

Comment: I would definitely think about copying all the data off that drive onto a new one at this point to be extra safe

Comment: Edit i changed the sata cable from 3gb slot to 6gbs and it works like normal no noise but my mouse pointer is a little slow

Comment: And I also unscrewed and screwed the hdd and it works fine but my mouse pointer is a little bit slow